# Interpolating polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

If I interpolate a polynomial of degree n with n+1 points, will I always get the polynomial itself back? if so, does it work for k < n+1 points?

Comment: "does it work for k < n+1 points?" what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $p,q$ are two polynomials of degree $n$ such that $p(x_i) = q(x_i)$ for $i=0, \dots ,n$. Then $p=q$.

In fact, if the polynomial $p-q \neq 0$, then it has $n+1$ distinct zeroes, but it has degree less than $n$: this is impossible.

Note that this argument does not work for a smaller number of points.

Now, if you have a polynomial of degree $n$, when you interpolate it on $n+1$ points you get a polynomial of degree $n$ coinciding on your original polynomial in those points. This means that you get your original polynomial back.

Comment: For the last part: how can you be certain that you get a polynomial of degree n back and not a polynomial of degree less than n?

Comment: Thanks. The theorems I have seen seem to only say that there is a unique polynomial p of degree at most n given n+1 points. Is the the always statement a special property for interpolating polynomials? is there a proof of it?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Uniqueness_of_the_interpolating_polynomial

Comment: Think I got it now, thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let $p(x)=x(1-x)$ and interpolate at abscissas $0$ and $1$. The Lagrangian interpolator will be identically zero.